# not able to do source NAT

Tags: networking, nat

My linux board has 2 interfaces one physical eth1 and another tap interface tun0. i need to forward all the packets with source IP as tun0 IP to eth1 IP.
So i was thinking of using natting. I used the where `2001:db8:0:f101::1/64` is `tun0` ip and `fd01:cab:1:16::190/64` is the `eth1` IP.

```
ip6tables -t nat -A INPUT/POSTROUTING --source 2001:db8:0:f101::1 -j SNAT --to-source fd01:cab:1:16::190

root@xxxxxxxxx:/mnt/mainfs/local# ifconfig eth1
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:6A:0A:5B:17:07
          inet addr:172.63.102.18  Bcast:172.63.102.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a6a:aff:fe5b:1707/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: fd01:cab:1:16::190/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1685 errors:0 dropped:3 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2433 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:213026 (208.0 KiB)  TX bytes:409380 (399.7 KiB)
          Interrupt:168

root@xxxxxxxxx:/mnt/mainfs/local# ifconfig tun0
tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet6 addr: 2001:db8:0:f101::1/64 Scope:Global
          UP POINTOPOINT NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I am trying to ping one machine `fc01:eab:96:1::4` from my board, but ping is not happening. Is my SNAT command proper??

```
root@msmci-ASK170100080:/mnt/mainfs/local# ping6 fc01:eab:96:1::4 -I 2001:db8:0:f101::1
PING fc01:eab:96:1::4 (fc01:eab:96:1::4) from 2001:db8:0:f101::1: 56 data bytes


root@msmci-ASK170100080:/mnt/mainfs/local# ping6 fc01:eab:96:1::4
PING fc01:eab:96:1::4 (fc01:eab:96:1::4): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fc01:eab:96:1::4: seq=0 ttl=61 time=1.840 ms
64 bytes from fc01:eab:96:1::4: seq=1 ttl=61 time=1.544 ms
^C
--- fc01:eab:96:1::4 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
```

Comment: You have enabled forwarding? The FORWARD chain accepts as default policy, or you have proper rules? I also recommend MASQUERADE (automatic choice of new source address) instead of SNAT.

Comment: For now i have ACCEPT all packets by below command      :                          ip6tables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT;
    ip6tables -I OUTPUT -j ACCEPT;
    ip6tables -I FORWARD -j ACCEPT